# Set tick step when x Axis is displaying a date in Python Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

This is my data

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])    
dfg = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'), 'direction']).size().to_frame('counts')
dfg.reset_index(inplace=True)

layout = Layout(
    title='Foo',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', 
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, ..., 5, 6, 7, ..., 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, ...],
    )
)

fig = go.Figure()

for d,c in zip(dfg['direction'].unique(), ['red','green']):
    dfs = dfg.query('direction == @d')
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=dfs['Date'],
            y=dfs['counts'],
            mode='lines',
            line=dict(
                color=c,
                width=3
            ),
            name=d
        )
    )

fig.show()
```

How would I set the ticks on the x Axis to every month or every week?

Comment: The data in question will collapse the scale, but try the following for a limited period of time. `fig.update_xaxes(type='date', dtick=86400000.0*7)`

Comment: @r-beginners this does not do the trick. There are no additional ticks on the x-axis

Comment: @r-beginners perfect, thanks. You can remove the link!